# HTTP Error 500.30 error when app.Run() have an async delegate method in .NET 7

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using .NET 7 web API application and I facing some issues to configure my application.
In my application just wanted to show that API is Running like message in the base URL, however, when I try to do that it is throwing error like **HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start**. I have done what I wanted to do in .NET 5 and 6 Web API applications. but this time this is not working for me. I have use the `app.Run(async (con)=>{});` to do that like below=>

```
 app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en\"><head><title>Base   API is Running</title></head><body><h3>Base API is Running</h3>");
            });
```

and out always look like this(in .NET 5 or 6)
[image]

but for the same code in .NET 7 it throws errors. On the other hand, if I remove the `async` part and write app.Run(); application works fine like below.
[image]

Here is my .NET 7 program.cs file code link please check and let me know=> https://pastebin.com/q84DLSsD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In my application just wanted to show that API is Running like
> message in the base URL, however, when I try to do that it is throwing
> error like HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start. I
> have done what I wanted to do in .NET 5 and 6 Web API applications.
> but this time this is not working for me

I have checke your shared code snippet on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/q84DLSsD). As you may know in  app.Run we cannot pass context directly as  `app.Run(async (context)` we either need to use [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to use [RequestDelegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.useextensions.use?view=aspnetcore-7.0) consequently, you are getting 500.30. In addition, It might work in previous version; hence, from dotnet 6 it wouldn't.

Solution:

If you want to pass the context while your application is running you can do it by following approach:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var yourMessage = "Base API is Running...";
    await context.Response.WriteAsync(page(yourMessage));
    await next(context);
});
```

Or you can directly pass your html as following:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        var yourMessage = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en\"><head><title>Base   API is Running</title></head><body><h3>Base API is Running</h3>";
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(yourMessage);
        await next(context);
    });
```

Even you can use seperate app.Run with o[verloading but cannot override the existing one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-7.0#middleware-class) you can write following code above main app.Run:

```
    app.Run(async (context) =>
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(
            "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en\"><head><title>Base   API is Running</title></head><body><h3>Base API is Running</h3>");
    });
app.Run();
```

You can directly pass your html in above code within response.Write; However, I prefer to call in another static method for the sake of readibility.

```
static string page(string message)
{
    return
        @"<!DOCTYPE html>
            <title>Base   API is Running
            </title >
            <body>
            <h3> " + message + @"
            </h3>
            </body>
            </html>";
}
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on [ApplicationBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.iapplicationbuilder?view=aspnetcore-7.0) you could [check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.useextensions.use?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-builder-useextensions-use(microsoft-aspnetcore-builder-iapplicationbuilder-system-func((microsoft-aspnetcore-http-httpcontext-system-func((system-threading-tasks-task))-system-threading-tasks-task))))

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce the problem with .NET 7. `app.Run(RequestDelegate)` is a extension method that adds a middleware to the app using the `Use()` method.

When I tried the original code with .NET 6 is wouldn't startup either for me. I am not sure why this would have worked for you.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Extension methods for adding terminal middleware.
    /// </summary>
    public static class RunExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Adds a terminal middleware delegate to the application's request pipeline.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="app">The <see cref="IApplicationBuilder"/> instance.</param>
        /// <param name="handler">A delegate that handles the request.</param>
        public static void Run(this IApplicationBuilder app, RequestDelegate handler)
        {
            if (app == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(app));
            }

            if (handler == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(handler));
            }

            app.Use(_ => handler);
        }
    }
}
```

I believe the `app.Run(RequestDelegate)` does not actually run the application.
If I add `app.Run()` after your `app.Run((context) => ...)`, the application starts up fine. But then I would use `app.Use(Func<RequestDelegate, RequestDelegate>)` for the middleware for more readability.

```
app.Run(async (context) =>
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en\"><head><title>Base   API is Running</title></head><body><h3>Base API is Running</h3>");
});

app.Run();
```